# Filmstrip animation similar to qz.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a filmstrip animation effect on scrolling similar to qz.com does on the videos. https://qz.com/

Do you know how to achieve this using jquery?

Comment: Attach a scroll listener to the body, then set the videos currentTime property based on the scroll progress relative to the values from getBoundingClientRect().

Comment: So don't need to use sprite image it can be achieved with current time?

Comment: Just tried it, works fine in chrome. Can't tell how it goes in other browsers.
If you care about performance, qz's solution is probably the best, but imho it's too much effort if your server can't render videos to such stripes.

Comment: Do you have a code i can try ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $video = $('video');
    var $window = $(window);
    var totalTime = 6; // total time you want to play

    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {

        if($video[0].getBoundingClientRect().top < $window.height() && $video[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0) {

            var progress = 100 - 100 / ($window.height() + $video.height()) * ($video[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + $video.height());
            $video[0].currentTime = Math.round(totalTime / 100 * progress);
            $video[0].paused = true;

        }

    });
</script>
```

Adjust totalTime to control how many seconds will be viewable.
Basically the scroll function checks if the video is visible in viewport, and if so, it calculates a progress between 0 and 100% which will then be used to calculate the currentTime.